# Aix-en-Provence TGV station blocked by cabbies?

Tags: trains, france, transportation, taxis

I heard this was planned and my train goes on the 18th, does anyone know if it's happening?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where have you heard this? What is planned?

Comment: @MarkMayo Taxis blocking the road leading to the station, per the question title. It was reported in the news (e.g. http://www.francebleu.fr/infos/taxis/circulation-tres-perturbee-le-11-juin-par-une-mobilisation-des-taxis-1584117), but it was last week so I think it's a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only relevant to a specific moment in time and has no historical interest or generalizable value.

Comment: @Giles we have several time-critical questions (eg unstable situation in March 2012 in Egypt was one of them).  To the OP - it wasn't clear from your title if it was the road, the station, the platforms etc, which is why I asked.

Comment: This is too specific to a single date, and also it happened in the past (11th June) so it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of anything like that. It happened last week but taxi protests usually don't last that long, if only because they often get a much softer treatment from the government than rail workers. However, I guess it's possible they would stage another protest exactly one week after the first one.

Also note that only public sector employees and civil servants have to officially warn before going on strike (“préavis de grève”). Private sector employees can just go on strike without warning and many taxi drivers are not employees or protested with their employer's approval (they did announce last week's protests in advance, though). So they might stop working or even disrupt traffic illegally without forewarning (in the past, farmers or truck drivers did that too without always publicly announcing precisely where they would put roadblocks).